# Is it possible to save variables set/changed in play mode?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was trying to make a Stardew Valley-esque day manager where the in-game day, season, and or year is changed by interacting with a bed, but once play mode is exited, the variables are reverted back. I tried to set the variables within a StartCoroutine, and while in play mode, it worked and the variables were changed, but when I exited play mode, the variables reverted back.

Comment: There is no built in function for that. You need to write your own editor script or just use one from asset store like [this](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/play-mode-saver-104836) one.

Comment: @ÇağatayIŞIK `There is no built in function for that.` .. I would say use e.g. [`PlayerPrefs`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) .. it is built-in and probably enough to do what is asked for ... in long term you might rather go for more robust external save file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To persist data you probably need to save your variables somewhere else like a database. For this you can just use a txt file. Maybe just look up how to write and read data to a file.
Do something like this:
When you start the game read the data
Right before closing the game write (update) the data